# How to test if database is hosted on SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to test whether a database is hosted on SQL Azure? I am looking at SqlAzureExecutionStrategy for EF6 and only want to apply if the database is actually SQL Azure database.

Currently I am testing if App is running within Azure. However we are looking at allowing clients to host DB themselves so would like some way to identify if DB is a SQL Server or Azure SQL.

Assume EF won't know as it is hiding the implementation details.

Could just have a config setting I guess. Just wondered if it was technically possible.

Comment: Can't you just run `SELECT @@version` - it will be something like 
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) – 11.0.1465.26 Aug 10 2011 22:54:49 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*Updated August 2021 to align with updated documentation*

```sql
SELECT CASE ServerProperty('EngineEdition')
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Personal'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Standard'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Enterprise'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Express'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'SQL Database'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Azure Synapse Analytics'
         WHEN 8 THEN 'Azure SQL Managed Instance'
         WHEN 9 THEN 'Azure SQL Edge'
         WHEN 11 THEN 'Azure Synapse serverless SQL pool'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
       END
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx

Answer (score 17):

I've been using the same function as gvee, ServerProperty(), but with a different property name:

```
IF ServerProperty('Edition') = 'SQL Azure'
    PRINT 'true'
```

For me, this is easier to read and also self-documenting.

Comment: I was using this code as well, but then I found a case where it didn't work because of collation issue. Check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/317945/collation-conflict-when-comparing-sql-variant-with-varchar-literal