# How do I know if I'm using an Azure SQL Database or an Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm working in a cloud server where I'm writing SQL in SSMS.  I'm just a simpleton data analyst by the way.  I was wondering if there was any SQL I could write to let me know if I am using an Azure SQL DB or an Azure SQL DW

Comment: Do any of the things in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582195/how-to-test-if-database-is-hosted-on-sql-azure help resolve the distinction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SERVERPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) system function to get different information about the installed SQL Server.

```sql
SELECT  
  SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS ComputerName,
  SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS InstanceName,  
  SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition, --SQL Azure
  SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') AS EditionID, -- 1674378470 = SQL Database or Azure Synapse Analytics
  SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS EngineEdition, -- 5 = SQL Database, 6 = Microsoft Azure Synapse Analytics, 11 = Azure Synapse serverless SQL pool  
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,  
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel;  
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

**Solution1:**
We can use `SELECT @@version` to distinguish the type of database.

1. Execute following script in User DB in Azure SQL DB

```
SELECT @@version
```

It returns `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Apr 29 2021 13:52:20   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation`

2. Execute following script in Dedicated SQL pool in Azure SQL DW

```
SELECT @@version
```

It returns `Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.16003.0 Apr 28 2021 04:55:16 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation`

**Solution2:**
As Venkataraman said, we can judge by `EngineEdition` property as follows

```sql
SELECT  
  SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS EngineEdition -- 5 = SQL Database, 6 = Microsoft Azure Synapse Analytics, 11 = Azure Synapse serverless SQL pool  
GO
```